# Masstransit queues prefixed with bus and postfixed with random string

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am taking over a project where Masstransit is being used as abstraction over RabbitMQ.

I see a lot of queues prefixed with "bus" and postfixed with some random character string.

What are theses queues being used for and how are they created? Any hint will be most welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's temporary queues. [more info in documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html)

And [this class](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport/Configuration/Configurators/ServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.cs) of MassTransit generates it (see `CreateTemporaryQueueName` method invoking)

Comment: Thanks. However I cannot find anything in the documentation link that explains about this. What is a temp queue created?

Comment: Every bus instance creates a temporary queue which is removed once the bus is stopped (or the process exits).

Comment: Start here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html#connecting-to-an-existing-bus

Comment: Temporary queues in particular are used for request-response.

Comment: Can I switch them off if I don't need them?