# MassTransit with RabbitMQ auto generated queues

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have used MassTransit with RabbitMQ in my project. I create my own queues such as `booking.hotel.live`. It works well but I see some auto-generated queues in my RabbitMQ queues list. For example :

`WINTECH04B7J11_EventConsumer_bus_bf5oyynsyyyfbtsrbdm175wjrh.`

What is that mean? What is the usage of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary queues are used for request-response.

Already asked and answered a few times, like [Masstransit queues prefixed with bus and postfixed with random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026670/masstransit-queues-prefixed-with-bus-and-postfixed-with-random-string)